# Problem with using numpy.fromfunction() to get 3D array output

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, 3d, mapping

**I have a problem with using the numpy.fromfunction() function while trying to get a 3D array as output.**

I used 3 parameters in lambda (i, j, k) and they should be just indices - (int, int, int). Instead of this, I get 3 numpy arrays with shape (100,100), so that:

```
    i.shape = (100, 100)
    j.shape = (100, 100)
    k.shape = (100, 100)
```

It crashed my lambda function because it needs 3 singe ints to work...

I used a function like in the documentation, but with 3 dimensions. Is the error in the numpy implementation?
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fromfunction.html#numpy.fromfunction

The documentation also says -
"The resulting array therefore has a value fn(x, y, z) at coordinate (x, y, z)."

Here is part of the code:

```
    check_reset_flag_fun = lambda i,j,k: self.dist_p_to_plane([i,j,k], plane_equation) > min_dist
    reset_flag_mtx = np.fromfunction(check_reset_flag_fun, (100,100,100), dtype=int)
    matrix[reset_flag_mtx] = reset_val
```

Comment: Read the docs literally, not as you hope it works.  Or from docs follow the [source] link to see what actually does.  It makes `indices` for the (a,b,c) shape and pases them to your function.  In other words it doesn't do anything significant.

Comment: `frompyfunc` is for functions with scalar inputs.  `Here the function has to accept arrays.

Comment: To quote **Each parameter represents the coordinates of the array varying along a specific axis**

Comment: You aren't the first to be confused by this function name and its documentation.  See this SO search: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bnumpy%5D+fromfunction

Answer (score 0):

I aprove the hpaulj answer, but still I think that this line from documentation can be misleading:

> The resulting array therefore has a value fn(x, y, z) at coordinate
> (x, y, z).

The result is rather fn(X, Y, Z), where X, Y, Z are indices arrays obtained from np.indices function for given shape.

I am not happy with the solution, It's quite messy, but here is my code:

```
check_reset_flag_fun = lambda i,j,k: self.dist_p_to_plane([i,j,k], plane_equation) > min_dist
def mapper(X, Y, Z):
    return np.array(list(map(check_reset_flag_fun, X.flatten(), Y.flatten(), Z.flatten()))).reshape((100,100,100))
            
reset_flag_mtx = np.fromfunction(mapper, (100,100,100), dtype=int)
b_result[reset_flag_mtx] = reset_val
```

To make it without np.fromfunction:

```
check_reset_flag_fun = lambda i,j,k: self.dist_p_to_plane([i,j,k], plane_equation) > min_dist
X, Y, Z = np.indices((100,100,100))
reset_flag_mtx = np.array(list(map(check_reset_flag_fun, X.flatten(), Y.flatten(), Z.flatten()))).reshape((100,100,100))
b_result[reset_flag_mtx] = reset_val
```

Here is also interesting code explaining how np.fromfunction works:

```
def fun(i, j):
    print("i shape\n", i.shape)
    print("j shape\n", j.shape)
    print("i\n", i)
    print("j\n", j)
    return i

res = np.fromfunction(lambda i, j: fun(i,j), (2, 2), dtype=float)
print("res\n", res)
```

output:

```
i shape
 (2, 2)
j shape
 (2, 2)
i
 [[0. 0.]
 [1. 1.]]
j
 [[0. 1.]
 [0. 1.]]
res
 [[0. 0.]
 [1. 1.]]
```